# Request object type-hinted in a library method throws missing argument error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, it's **[suggested](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#accessing-the-request)** to type-hint the Request object in controller method declarations:

I'm trying to do the same in one of my libraries:

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyLibrary {

    public static function doStuff(Request $request) {
        //...
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use the library method like shown in the code below, I get a missing argument error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\MyLibrary;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        MyLibrary::doStuff(); // => trows missing argument error
    }

}
```

Now, I've type-hinted the Request object into my `doStuff()` method. Why do I need to pass an argument? I thought that type-hinting is a way to inject needed resources into methods, so they don't have to be always passed directly. Do I understand the concept incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You declared a Method doStuff() which takes one argument and the Argument must be an instance of Request Class.

Typehinting just says what type the Argument must be.

for example

```
function sum(int $x, int $y) {
    return $x+$y;
}

sum(1,2); // ok
sum('1', 2); // error
```

so when you call doStuff you must pass the request yourself.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\MyLibrary;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $request = get regest object from laravel;
        MyLibrary::doStuff($request);
    }

}
```

read more about type declarations at php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: So I understand there's some internal magic happening in Laravel when it comes to type-hinting and controllers, am I right? Like in declaring a controller action: `public function update(Request $request, $id)` - the `update` method needs the `id` to be passed, but the `Request` param is handled internally, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a method with just `MyLibrary::doStuff()` then what you ask for is exactly what happens - `doStuff` method is called without any arguments, hence the error.

If you want any services injected into the method, you need to call the method using the service container. The following code should do the trick:

```
\App::call(['App\Libraries\MyLibrary', 'doStuff']);
```

Service container will look at type hints and inject a value if it has it.